# Disable HWE and continue with GA kernal of 16.04?

Tags: 16.04, kernel, lts, downgrade

My Laptop is very old and doesn't need support for new hardware. Updating to new kernel releases has made me 2nd monitor not to work. How can I opt out of HWE and stay with 5years supported kernel? I don't need new Linux kernels every 6months or so. In server installations GA kernel is the default, is there any option like that in desktop(laptop) version. Please help.

Comment: You can pick the kernel version you like and freeze the system there. I believe it is called `apt` pinning but on my phone now.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop using the HWE kernel and go back to the GA kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-to-stop-using-the-hwe-kernel-and-go-back-to-the-ga-kernel)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable hwe-support on ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335453/how-can-i-disable-hwe-support-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want the `ga` kernel, install the `linux-generic` kernel packages and then remove the `linux-generic-hwe-16.04` kernel packages.

Reference: https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/RollingLTSEnablementStack

Comment: Thanks, I had installed ga kernel successfully (using sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-xenial linux-generic-lts-xenial
) and just want to keep hwd kernel. Can i create separate GRUB entries for ga and hwe kernel like Ubuntu_ga and Ubuntu_hwd ( grub customizer could be used but i guess i have to change entries  every time kernel updates )

Comment: Apologies, but can you give insight into how to do that? Like a step-by-step?

Comment: @NessDan step-by-step answers would be for 16.04, which is probably not what you want. Best to ask a new question, specifying what version of Ubuntu you are using.