# How can I disable hwe-support on ubuntu 18.04?

Tags: apt, kernel

The OS is Ubuntu 18.04.5

I want to use GA kernel.

SO I do these operations:

```
it@it51:~$ sudo apt install linux-generic
```

Then reboot the machine.

I uninstall HWE kernel:

```
it@it51:~$ sudo apt-get purge linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04
it@it51:~$ sudo apt-get remove linux-generic-hwe-18.04
it@it51:~$ sudo apt-get remove xserver-xorg-hwe-18.04
```

Then reboot the machine.

Then I use this command:

```
it@it51:~$ sudo hwe-support-status
Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023.
```

Does the above paragraph (Your Hardware Enablement Stack (HWE) is supported until April 2023) show that I have not disabled hwe-support successfully?

What method can I use to disable hwe-support successfully?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop using the HWE kernel and go back to the GA kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-to-stop-using-the-hwe-kernel-and-go-back-to-the-ga-kernel)

Comment: Thanks very much !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a page over at [ubuntu.com](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack), which details downgrading to the GA kernel for 20.04.  They don't have specific instructions for 18.04, but they look like they should be the same:

> To downgrade from HWE/OEM to GA kernel:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-generic
> ```
>
> If NVIDIA drivers are required check appropriate level and install
> them:
>
> ```
> ubuntu-drivers list
> ```
>
> And then install appropriate NNN version of the drivers:
>
> ```
> sudo apt install --install-recommends linux-modules-nvidia-NNN-generic
> ```
>
> Reboot, interrupt grub, in advanced options elect to boot 5.4 based
> kernel, complete boot. Check that everything works as expected.
>
> If everything is good, you may remove the other kernel flavours:
>
> ```
> sudo apt remove --purge linux-generic-hwe-20.04 linux-oem-20.04 linux-hwe-* linux-oem-* linux-modules-5.1* linux-modules-5.8.0-* linux-modules-5.6.0-*
> ```

Comment: Advice:
  Use the string in the below line to replace " linux-modules-5.1* linux-modules-5.8.0-* linux-modules-5.6.0-*" within the above command
  $(dpkg -l  linux-modules-5* | grep -v  linux-modules-5.4. )

Comment: the line should be:   dpkg -l linux-modules-5* | .... 
* is missing...  it cannot be shown