# Why same distribution release has different major kernels?

Tags: upgrade, kernel

Last week a person created a ubuntu 18.04 LTS in Amazon Cloud (AWS) to match my home Linux. Somehow when I logged into it, I see very different kernel version.

AWS

```
aws$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS"

aws$ uname -a
Linux aws 5.4.0-1078-aws #84~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 3 12:59:49 UTC 2022
```

Home

```
home$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=bionic
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS"

home$ uname -a
Linux home 4.15.0-112-generic #113-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jul 9 23:41:39 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I can understand if minor version changed due to upgrade, eg, 4.15 vs 4.22. But this is a major version difference: 4 vs 5. Will my binary executable still be portable?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack uses 4.15, using the HWE kernel stack it is 5.4 (being the GA kernel stack from 20.04).  See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack but other OEM kernel stack options exist too.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable hwe-support on ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335453/how-can-i-disable-hwe-support-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: FYI:  If your system reports as 18.04.2, you're behind on upgrades though so check that.  A fully upgraded system should report as [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) as your AWS example shows...   FYI: At 18.04.2 the HWE kernel was 4.18 (being the kernel from 18.10), final HWE kernel for 18.04.5 & later being 5.4 from 20.04..  *Installation media used sets the default kernel stack but it can be changed*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04 LTS using the GA kernel stack uses 4.15, using the HWE kernel stack it is 5.4 (being the GA kernel stack from 20.04).

See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack for more details, with other OEM kernel stack options existing too. The installation media used determines the default kernel stack used.

FYI:  If your system reports as 18.04.2, you're behind on upgrades though so I'd check that.  A fully upgraded system should report as [18.04.6](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/09/17/ubuntu-18-04-6-lts-released/) as your AWS example shows...   At 18.04.2 the HWE kernel was 4.18 (being the kernel from 18.10), final HWE kernel for 18.04.5 & later being 5.4 from 20.04..

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I didn't realize this opened a can of worms. The amount of information is overwhelming. I almost upgraded my home Linux to HWE before I noticed so many posts regarding how to get out of HWE. I am very nervous about what HWE will do to my home Linux.

Comment: On many of my home machines I have both (GA & HWE) stacks installed as costs are low being more to upgrade (*both get fixes*), slightly more disk space used but more choice & greater chance to troubleshoot (*most for others not myself*). On *much* older hardware I tend to find GA kernel is *generally* better, on newer hardware its HWE; but for most its identical. If using closed-source (*proprietary*) kernel modules (nvidia etc) both may not be able to co-exist; but I mostly use all open source anyway.  Having choice gives us more options & Ubuntu LTS provides that choice.