# I am running Ubuntu 22.04; how to prevent kernel being changed from v 5.15 to 5.19?

Tags: kernel

Ubuntu 22.04 is stable running kernel v 5.15. However, when uploads come along the kernel gets changed to v 5.19. I have found that I lose sound and ability to read exfat files with v 5.19 which is corrected when I go back to v 5.15. How do I prevent kernel being changed to v 5.19 ?

Comment: If you only have the GA kernel stack installed; you'll be using the 5.15 kernel for the life of the product.  Only installs that have the HWE kernel stack packages will or have upgraded to 5.19 (at 22.04.2), and will soon upgrade to 6.2 (currently in *proposed*, but its part of 22.04.3).   Your packages & details set by installation media determine what you have installed for your *unstated* 22.04 product (GA is default for Server installs for example).  https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable hwe-support on ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335453/how-can-i-disable-hwe-support-on-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: I mentioned Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Server installs made with Server media defaults to the GA kernel stack; as does installs made with Lubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 LTS media, plus Xubuntu 22.04 & 22.04.1 LTS media... however with Lubuntu & Xubuntu 22.04.2 LTS or *later* media the HWE kernel stack is installed by default ... ie. the installation media sets the default. Ubuntu 22.04 LTS Desktop media defaults to HWE by default; but can be changed as per documentation (as it can with all 22.04 installs)... The *flavors* I mention are only used as examples... some install media can also install OEM & more.

Comment: Thanks for your time..... I am using 22.04.2 lts. So do I understand that it will always upgrade to 5.19 and I have to change back to 5.15 every time the system is upgraded ? ( I am not an expert on Linux !)

Comment: Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has more than a single kernel stack option... if you installed your system with 5.15 and GA kernel stack defaults; your system will keep & only use the 5.15 kernel for the life of your product, which I tried to explain (this is the default if any Server ISO is used, or some *flavor* 22.04 or 22.04.1 media is used). It will only change to 5.19 or a HWE (soon it won't be 5.19 but 6.2 which is the next *edge* kernel currently in *proposed*) as that is the HWE kernel **option**. It will **not** upgrade to 5.19 unless your system has that default (ie. default set to remain GA)

Comment: Many thanks for your time .... I am not sure which kernel was specified when the system was installed .... presumably 5.19 as default. Is it just case of specifying 5.15 as default kernel  in the GRUB loader ?  Apologies for not being  familiar with  Linux terminology

Comment: You've not said what Ubuntu 22.04 product you're using; only the Server installer lets you choose the kernel stack, with Desktop ISOs you decide **before** you download the ISO & select the ISO that installs the kernel stack you want (*I mentioned that using Lubuntu & Xubuntu as examples in a prior comment*).  If using a Desktop system (*you've not said*) your decision was made when you started downloading...

Comment: Thanks again - I confirm that I am using a Desktop system. Perhaps I am going to have to reload the system. Shame as the system is stable apart from the recurrent exfat issue.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to stop using the HWE kernel and go back to the GA kernel?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1306358/how-to-stop-using-the-hwe-kernel-and-go-back-to-the-ga-kernel)