# Kernel 6.2 have issues on webcam, need to use an older one as default

Tags: kernel, dell, webcam

Some weeks ago my Ubuntu installation on my Dell Latitude E7470 received kernel 6.2 (now 6.2.0-31-generic), but this update raises issue on my webcam.
I can do meetings as usual but the image is flickering continuously because, I suppose, is continuing adjust brightness to react to environmental light.
I try to boot with an older kernel, my case 5.19 and the issue disappeared. Given the facts that:

- kernel 6.2 has some issue on the topic
- kernel 5.19 seems discontinued

I need to find a way to use, as default so it should be something reboot/update proof, a previous kernel version that should be at this time 5.15.0-60-generic still installed.

Thanks for any advice

Comment: Run the command `lsusb`. Edit your question to include the line of that output that is your camera. Show us that complete line.

Comment: You've not mentioned what release you're using, but Ubuntu 22.04 LTS has two supported kernel stacks (*I'm skipping OEM stacks for simplicity here*), being 5.15 or the GA kernel stack, & HWE which is now 6.2 (*it was 5.19 not long back; 6.2 from 23.04 & 5.19 from 22.10*) thus if your release is 22.04 or *jammy*, then 5.15 is a supported kernel.  You didn't mention your release though (*6.2 is the kernel from 23.04, which is where 22.04 gets it*)

Comment: Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting . Take the [tour].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I disable hwe-support on ubuntu 18.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335453/how-can-i-disable-hwe-support-on-ubuntu-18-04)